# Append data in file after time

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I created a method that append data to file .txt and it executes on Button_Click method. But I want to save the data to file not when I click the button but after time automatically (ex. after couple minutes starting from Application_Start). How can I solve my problem?

```
 static public bool appendToFileTxt(string input)
        {
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(nameOfFile))
                    File.Copy(nameOfFile, nameOfFile + ".bak", true);
                        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(nameOfFile, true)){
                                sw.WriteLine(input.Replace("\r", ""));
                        }
                return true;
            }
            catch{
                return false;
            }
        }



protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             appendToFileTxt(newInput);
        }
```

Comment: Use System.Threading.Timer

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) class for this usage.

```
// Simulate Application_Start
public static void Main()
{
    var appendToFileTimer = new Timer(AppendToFile, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
}

public static void AppendToFile(Object state)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Append to file");
}
```